# ASP.NET MVC com FormsAuthentication

Tags: c#, mvc, forms-authentication

Tenho uma aplicação Asp.net MVC com FormsAuthentication, mas surgiu a necessidade de liberar uma página para o visitante do site ou seja uma página fica liberada para todo mundo e o restante dos controllers cai na tela de login, é possível?

Comment: Você está usando o Authorize para fazer a autenticação? Se for, tente usar o atributo AllowAnonymous para isso.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727509/how-to-allow-an-anonymous-user-access-to-some-given-page-in-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode liberar a seguinte controller colocando este código no seu Web.config

```
 <location path="ControllerName">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
 </location>
```

Caso você esteja utilizando o Authorize, você poderá colocar no método a implementação de  [AllowAnonymous] como annotation do mesmo para liberar para usuários não autenticados.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível. No seu controller, ou sobre a sua Action, você deve ter um atributo "[Authorize]". Todas as actions com este atributo significam que só podem ser acessadas se o usuário estiver autenticado, as páginas que você quiser deixar como públicas, nas Actions correspondentes, você não coloca este atributo. Uma vez colocado o atributo no controller significa que qualquer action daquele controller precisa de autenticação.

Você também consegue configurar isso via Web.config, porém acho que o atributo é mais simples.

Comment: Obrigado Jhonathan e Rodrigo!